# Sock-shop on GCP with Loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am trying to deploy and access Sock-shop on Google Cloud Platform.
https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo

I was able to deploy it using the deployment script 
https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/complete-demo.yaml

Based on the tutorial here 
https://www.weave.works/docs/cloud/latest/tasks/deploy/sockshop-deploy/
It says 
Display the Sock Shop in the browser using:

`<master-node-IP>:<NodePort>`

But on GCP master node is hidden from the user.

So I changed the type from NodePort to LoadBalancer.

And I was able to get an external IP.

But it says the page cannot be found. `enter code here`

Do I need to set up more stuff for LoadBalancer?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know If you solve the issue but I did it so I would like to share with you my solution that works for me.
You can do it through two ways:

1st) By creating a Load Balancer, where you expose the front-end service.
I assume that you have already created a namespace called sock-shop so any further command should specify and referred to that namespace. 
If you type and execute the command:

`kubectl get services --namespace=sock-shop`

you should be able to see a list with all the services included a service called "front-end". So now you want to expose that service not as NodePort but as LoadBalancer. So, execute the command:

`kubectl expose service front-end --name=front-end-lb --port=80 --target-port=8079 --type=LoadBalancer --namespace=sock-shop`

After this give some time and you will able to access the Front end of the Sock Shop via public IP address (ephimeral)

2nd) More advanced way is by configuring an Ingress Load Balancer. 
You need to configure another yaml file and put this code inside and run it as you did with the previous .yaml file.

```
nano basic-ingress.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace : sock-shop
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: front-end
    servicePort: 80

kubectl apply -f basic-ingress.yaml --namespace=sock-shop
```

Locate the Public IP address through this command and after maximun 15mins you should be able to access the Sock Shop.

```
kubectl get ingress --namespace=sock-shop
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Your 1st solution worked flawlessly for my deployment in Azure KS. 

However, I've been trying to create an Ingress Load Balancer as you have suggested. For some reason I'm not getting the address.. I was wondering if you had any idea as for why this could be.. ? The output looks like this 

`kubectl get ingress --namespace=sock-shop`
`NAME            CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE`
`basic-ingress   <none>   *                 80      43m`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to return back for `NodePort` in the corresponded Service and create `Ingress` resource in your GCP cluster.

If you desire to access the related application from outside the cluster, Kubernetes provides [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) mechanism to expose HTTP and HTTPS routes to your internal services.

Basically, [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) is created by default in GKE once `Ingress` resource has been implemented successfully, therefore it will take care for routing all the external HTTP/S traffic to the nested Kubernetes services.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 8080
```

You can check the External IP address for Load Balancer by the following command:

`kubectl get ingress basic-ingress`

I found this [Article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) would be very useful in your common research.